# Webpack 2 code splitting with System.import: Dependencies of dependencies

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, code-splitting

Okay so I am working on properly splitting our JS in a bunch of asynchronously loaded chunks.

I am using `import` in several entry points, and that works great:

```
module.exports = Promise.all([
    import('moment'),
    import('some-other-module')
]).then((deps) => {
    let [moment, someOtherModule] = deps;
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
module.exports = Promise.all([
    import('moment'),
]).then((deps) => {
    let [moment] = deps;
}
```

Webpack successfully creates separate chunks for `moment` and `some-other-module`
 and loads the files async when needed.

**However:**

`some-other-module` actually requires `moment` as well, making Webpack include `moment` also in `some-other-module`'s chunk, leading to duplication.

Is this the expected behaviour? And if so, what is the recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line of code to my plugins section of webpack.config which separates the dependencies and loads them as required in parallel

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    async: true
})
```

you can see the description of CommonsChunkPlugin async on this page
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/